# How to make a connection with MySql database from my CPanel with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to make a connection to MySQL database from my cpanel with Visual studio, but I keep getting an error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I have installed both MySql for Visual studio and Connector/net. I have tried with both Server Explorer and through the code using the connection string. I have added my ip to the access host list on Remote MySql in CPanel. But nothing worked.

```
namespace Program
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
        string connectionString = @"SERVER=mydomain.net;DATABASE=mydatabasename;UID=myuser;PASSWORD=mypass";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillDropDown(DropDownList1);
        }

        public void FillDropDown(DropDownList dropDown)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from MyTable", sqlCon);
                    sqlCon.Open();
                    dropDown.DataSource = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                    dropDown.DataBind();
                    dropDown.DataTextField = "Name";
                    dropDown.DataValueField = "Id";


                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                lblError.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You mention MySQL but the error message says SQL Server. Those 2 are different databases engines. Make sure to use the proper connection object.

Answer (score 1):

The SqlConnection-object may only be used for connections to MS-SqlServers. You have to use MySqlConnection to connect to MySql-server. This also applies to the SqlCommand.
Furthermore the used connection-string is not valid for MySql ('Password' should be 'Pwd') Compare your string to https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: Great thanks. But now I am getting error: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. Is this has something to do with settings on my Cpanel maybe?

Comment: I tried with MySql Benchmark and with Server Explorer in Visual studio and also I tried with all possible con stings, but I still can't connect with any of those. Not sure what am I doing wrong. For server I am using my domain and I also tried IP of my domain that I have in Cpanel. For database I have put my database name and user name and password is from my user that I created for that database.

Comment: Your db-user is probably configured wrong. A db-user in MySql looks something like this '<username>@<client>'. This means that the username as well as the client must match. If for example your root-user is only setup as 'root@localhost', the server will only allow connections from localhost when logging in as root. To enable all clients you need to create a user like '<name>@%'. refer to: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-users.html